# I need some help with the Windows installer

Tags: wubi

I am having some trouble installing Ubuntu 12.04 with the Windows installer. The instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows say (in step 7) that I chose to boot with Ubuntu, but the black screen doesn't come up: it just goes straight to Windows. I've tried to boot it from a USB stick but it won't read it until Windows boots up.  So can anyone help me?

Some computer info:

- HP pavilion 520n
- not on the internet
- Windows XP Home edition version 2002 Service pack 2
- Intel(R) Celeron(TM) CPU 1300MHz
- 1.30 GHz, 510 MB of RAM

I think that's all you'll need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, hit 'start', then 'run', and type in `msconfig` and press enter. Click on the boot tab on top of the window that opens up, and look through those settings. One of them might be disabling the boot manager.

I'm pretty new too, so I hope this helps!